# Why does $b^{\log_bx} = x$?

Tags: logarithms

Why does $b^{\log_bx} = x$?

Can someone break this down by showing me the steps as to why this is true?

Comment: It's probably the definition of logarithm; or did you have a different definition in mind?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the definition of the base-$b$ logarithm.

$\log_b c=d \Leftrightarrow b^d=c$.

So putting $y=\log_b x$ we have $b^y=x$.  That is $b^{\log_b x}=x$.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Thanks for the clean up!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think of this is to define a family of functions for any $b > 0$:  $$f_b(x) = b^x.$$  Then there is an inverse function $$f_b^{-1}(x)$$ such that $$f_b^{-1}(f_b(x)) = x$$ for all real $x$, and $$f_b(f_b^{-1}(x)) = x$$ on the domain of the inverse function, which happens to be for $x > 0$.  The inverse function **is** the logarithm:  $$f_b^{-1}(x) = \log_b x.$$  Thus, $\log_b x^b = x$ and $b^{\log_b x} = x$ are consequences of the above and merely use **different notation** to express the same concept.

Another way to think about the base-$b$ logarithm is that *logarithms* are *exponents*.  That is to say, $\log_b x$ is the exponent or power to which $b$ must be raised in order to obtain $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$b^{\log_b(x)}=b^{\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(b)}}=\sqrt[\ln(b)]{b^{\ln(x)}}=\sqrt[\ln(b)]{x^{\ln(b)}}=x^{\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(b)}}=x^1=x$$